# How to assign labels and jobname for each job differently while using Flink system metrics

Tags: label, system, apache-flink, metrics

While running batch jobs on a flink session cluster we need to assign different labels and job names to each job to distinguish between their metrics. While pushing the Flink system metrics on a gateway, the config changes made in flink-conf.yaml include the config for the jobName, but then all the jobs would have the same name. Also how to assign labels to them? The configuration for jobName used in flink-conf.yaml is this

```
metrics.reporter.promgateway.jobName: myJob
```

but I want different names and labels everytime. How should I override this setting during job Submission?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
-yD metrics.reporter.promgateway.jobName= 'yourJobName'
```

When you submit your job